# How can I launch Windows Explorer with a particular Libraries folder open?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I can look up where the library is e.g. `GetRegKey("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders\Personal") & "\Job Applications"` but that doesn't open Explorer in `Libraries\Documents\My Documents\Job Applications`, it opens it in `D:\Users\philhibbs\Documents\Job Applications`. It is the same location really, but the aesthetics are a little different, and I'd prefer the former if possible. Does anyone know how to do this?